# how to show UIAlertvew then applicacation running in background

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uialertview

Im create application with timer  and show  pop ups evry 30 sec

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];



timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(30)
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(showpopup:) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];




}

-(void) showpopup:(NSTimer *)theTimer{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YAHooo!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
        [alert release];

}
```

How  change code to show pop ups in background mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't show UIAlertView when your application is in background. You can use UILocalNotification which comes in UIAlertView format, but there is a limit for number of notification for each app. To schedule UILocalNotification follow the [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/).

Comment: Can you help me how to add to Add NSTimer and UILocalNotification to appdelegate files to  show it every 30 sec?

Comment: NSTimer will not work when you are in the background, unless you start a background task.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: You can not use NSTimer you have to schedule all the notification with a time interval of 30 sec before entering in backgroud.